# template static variable undefined in class ctor

Tags: c++, templates

I have defined below hierarchy of classes, my intention is to design a generic class that allows me to iterate over enum objects (C++11 is not allowed to be used unfortunately). The class definition and test program are:

```
// base.h

#include <set>

template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
   explicit Base(int value);
   typedef typename std::set< Base<T>* > instances;
   static instances s_instances;
   int value_;


public:
   int get_value() const { return value_ ; }
};

template <typename T>
Base<T>::Base(int value): value_(value)
{
   s_instances.insert(this);
}
```

// derived.h

```
#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
protected:
    explicit Derived(int value): Base<Derived>(value) { }

public:
    static const Derived value1;
};
```

// test.cc

```
#include "derived.h"


template<>
Base<Derived>::instances Base<Derived>::s_instances;

const Derived Derived::value1(1);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;

   cout << Derived::value1.get_value() << endl;

}
```

On compilation using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, it gives me below linking error:
"

```
g++ test.cc -o test
/tmp/ccOdkcya.o: In function `Base<Derived>::Base(int)':
test.cc:(.text._ZN4BaseI7DerivedEC2Ei[_ZN4BaseI7DerivedEC5Ei]+0x28): undefined reference to `Base<Derived>::s_instances'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

"

Can anyone please suggest what am I missing in above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static data members are **declared** in class definitions and **defined** outside the class definition. Like this:

```
// header:
class C {
    static int i;
};

// source:
int C::i = 17;
```

With a template, you typically don't put any code in source files, so the definition goes in the header:

```
// header:
template <class T>
class C {
    static int i;
};

template <class T>
int C<T>::i = 17;
```

Comment: Thanks! Moving the declaration to derived.h such as:                template<>                                                          typename Base<T>::instances Base<T>::s_instances;                   works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write

```
// template<> -> you should not write this in this case.
Base<Derived>::instances Base<Derived>::s_instances;
```

If you have provided an explicit specialization of `Base<Derived>`, such as :

```
class Derived;
template <>
class Base<Derived>
{
protected:
  explicit Base(int value);
  typedef typename std::set< Base<Derived>* > instances;
  static instances s_instances;
  int value_;


public:
  int get_value() const { return value_ ; }
};
```

Otherwise, you have to stick to writing:

```
template<typename T>
typename Base<T>::instances Base<T>::s_instances;
```

Comment: Removing "template<>" gives following compilation error: g++ test.cc -g -o test
test.cc:8:26: error: specializing member ‘Base<Derived>::s_instances’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax

Comment: Yes - but did you provide a full specialization of Base<Derived> ? second block of code - it's needed for that syntax to be valid. Otherwise, you cannot specialize _only_ that part of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that s_instances might not have been initialized before it is used.

Comment: M not sure how that can happen. The static instances of Dervied class are set in test.cc a line below s_instances is initialized. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: "template<>
Base<Derived>::instances Base<Derived>::s_instances"
is not an initialization, it is a definition.